# xamarin android: click of an item by a list in a list

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I use MvvmCross and Xamarin. In my app I have a MvxListView with a nested MvxLinearLayout. How can I handle the click on the item of the LinearLayout?

This is my Code:

HTe List View:

The List

```
        <MvxListView
        android:id="@+id/category_list"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_item_selector"
        local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/listitem_inner_category_list"
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Source" />
```

The Inner List

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        local:MvxBind="Text Key" />
    <Mvx.MvxLinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/inner_category_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:clickable="true"
        local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/listitem_category"
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource .;ItemClick EditCommand" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The Item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:paddingLeft="6dp"
    android:paddingRight="6dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:translationZ="3dp">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        local:MvxBind="Text Name" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this in the inner list:

```
<MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.RecyclerView.MvxRecyclerView
      android:id="@+id/inner_category_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:clickable="true"
        local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/listitem_category"
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource .;ItemClick ItemClickCommand" />
```

It seemes that on the MvxLinearLayout is no ItemClick implemented :)